# Fineuploader Minio integration

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, fine-uploader, minio

Currently I'm having trouble with setting up FineUploader to work with Minio, since all the documentation available only applied to S3.

I have done all step necessary to integrate Minio to Laravel as describe here:
https://github.com/minio/cookbook/blob/master/docs/how-to-use-minio-as-laravel-file-storage.md
And test upload using Storage::disk('minio) or Storage::cloud() successfully.

Currently I want to upload file directly to Minio without having to upload it to application server first, so I use controller example from this repo:
https://github.com/FineUploader/php-laravel-s3-server

The errors I'm receiving:

```
...
[Fine Uploader 5.15.5] Sending simple upload request for 0
[Fine Uploader 5.15.5] Submitting S3 signature request for 0
[Fine Uploader 5.15.5] Sending POST request for 0
s3/endpoint Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status)
[Fine Uploader 5.15.5] POST request for 0 has failed - response code 419
[Fine Uploader 5.15.5] Response does not include the base64 encoded policy!
[Fine Uploader 5.15.5] Policy signing failed.  Response does not include the base64 encoded policy!
```

Likely trouble with policy signing as the code returning error on **line 73** on this file:
https://github.com/FineUploader/php-laravel-s3-server/blob/master/ExampleController.php

Can anyone share an example of working Minio integration with FineUploader?